# multiple side-by-side versions with Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Is it possible to install multiple versions side-by-side with Homebrew?

I find myself in a situation needing sbt-0.7.x, sbt-0.10.x and sbt-0.11.0. I've installed both sbt-0.7.7 and sbt-0.10.1 manually at the moment to work around the issue (with sbt-0.11.0 being the latest 'sbt' from Homebrew).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yeah. When you install a new version of a package, it keeps the old one. The symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` or wherever point to the latest version, but you can still call the binaries (or link to the libraries) in the older version.

`brew list` to see what's installed. You can look in package directories to see all the versions; or call `brew list --versions` to see all packages and all versions.

Comment: this behaviour has changed, brew now errors out of installing a new version of something unless you opt to upgrade (and remove old version)

Answer (score 35):

To easily switch between versions of formulae, you can use:

```
brew switch <formula> <version>
```

For example:

```
brew switch gradle 3.2.1
```

To list which versions you have installed try:

```
brew list --versions
```

or:

```
brew list <formula> --versions
```

If you want to get rid of older versions, just use:

```
brew cleanup
```

Comment: Brew switch has been removed from recent version of brew any other solution are available to easily switch between versions?

Comment: @NicolasForney `brew unlink <formula>` then `brew link <formula>`

Answer (score 9):

As of Homebrew 2.0.0, it would remove old packages automatically when `brew upgrade` is called. (https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/). To opt-out of this behavior, set the environment variable: `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=1`

Comment: Except when the package is `pin`'d.